# Navigate back to home screen in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

[Home Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv0ZD.png)
On the home screen when I click on a album cover I push the album cover page when I click on the home icon in the bottom navigation I want it to come back to the home page but it does not navigate back to the home page.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:spotify/screens/HOME/home.dart';
import 'screens/search.dart';

Map<Widget, GlobalKey<NavigatorState>> navigatorKeys = {
  const Home(): GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
  const Search(): GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
};

Widget selectView(int index) {
  return views[index];
}

List views = [Home(), Search()];

class Tabbar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Tabbar> createState() => _TabbarState();
}

class _TabbarState extends State<Tabbar>{
  int _selectedTab = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          elevation: double.infinity,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xff0d1117),
          selectedItemColor: Color(0xfff5f5f5),
          unselectedItemColor: Color(0xff333333),
          currentIndex: _selectedTab,
          onTap: (index) {
            print(<RouteStackItem>[])
            setState(() {
              _selectedTab = index;
            });
          },
          iconSize: 30,
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: "Home",
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search_outlined),
              label: "Search",
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.library_music),
              label: "Your Library",
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              label: "Profile",
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            _buildOffstageNavigator(0),
            _buildOffstageNavigator(1),
          ],
        )

        // _buildOffstageNavigator(2),
        // _buildOffstageNavigator(3),

        //Stack(
        //   children: [
        //     renderView(
        //       0,
        //       const Home(),
        //     ),
        //     renderView(
        //       1,
        //       const Search(),
        //     ),
        // renderView(
        //   2,
        //   LibraryView(),
        // ),
        // renderView(
        //   3,
        //   ProfileView(),
        // ),
        //   ],;
        );
  }

  Widget _buildOffstageNavigator(int tabItem) {
    return Offstage(
      offstage: _selectedTab != tabItem,
      child: Navigator(
        key: navigatorKeys[selectView(_selectedTab)],
        initialRoute: "/", // this is the route name
        onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => selectView(_selectedTab));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

tried popuntill but did it did not work and also pushAndRemoveuntill caused the bottom navbar disappear.